# Flutter Unable to load asset: but dir doesnt exist

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter throws these errors but the images he cant find does not exist!
the images that do exist are in the folder assets/images/ and have other (normal) names.
i imported them properly in pubspec.yaml
what can be the solution for this weird problem?

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/v.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:223:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:669:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:652:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
#4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:360:22)
#5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:80)
#6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:108:19)
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:334:9)
#8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:26)
(elided 13 frames from dart:async)

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/v.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#8dc86(), name: "assets/images/v.png",
  scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/v.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:223:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:669:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:652:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/v.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#8dc86(), name: "assets/images/v.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/images/e.png

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/images/e.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/images/h.png

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/images/h.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/images/i.png

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/images/i.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: It wont work if it is inide lib folder, check if that is the case

Comment: the dart files are inside the lib, the images are in the main dir of the project

Answer (score 1):

```
 you can go to pubspec.yaml and give folder path there
 assets:
- assets/images/

Don't need to give the name of image just give folder path then
```

run app again

Comment: `flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/`

my pubspec.yaml is already like this this is what messing me up!

Comment: please check indentation  
 assets:
    - assets/images/